# Use Range, Cells, to set a specific cell to a string, then merge and center?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to set a specific cell to the filename of the file that I just opened using my code.  I have everything working properly except I can't get the cell value to equal the workbook name.  When debugging my code, I can see that my variable for wb name is the correct string.  In the code below, when this subroutine is called, wbTempName is passed as the path of the workbook that was just opened (I think), and iTemp is just an integer that was the first empty column (found in a separate subroutine).  Here is the code:

```
Sub CMM_93Cam(ByVal wbTempName As Workbook, ByVal iTemp As Integer)
'
' CMM_93Cam Macro
'
    'Set necessary variables
    sColumnTwo = ConvertToLetter(iTemp + 2)

    'Paste filename into sheet
    wbTempName.Activate
    sWBName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Range(Cells(2, iTemp)).Value = sWBName
    Range(Cells(2, iTemp), Cells(2, iTemp + 2)).Select
    Selection.Merge

'Code that works

End Sub
```

When I call this code, I get a runtime error 1004 on the "Range(Cells(2, iTemp)).Value = sWBName" line:  "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed".

The other issue is, I don't think that my code to merge and center the indicated cells was working (I originally had it before the line where I try to set the cell value, thinking that it was causing problems).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code as follows:

```
Sub CMM_93Cam(ByVal wbTempName As Workbook, ByVal iTemp As Integer)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Set necessary variables
    sColumnTwo = ConvertToLetter(iTemp + 2)

    'Paste filename into sheet
    sWBName = wbTempName.Name

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Cells(2, iTemp).Value = sWBName
        .Range(.Cells(2, iTemp), .Cells(2, iTemp + 2)).Merge
    End With

    'Code that works
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Note**, that this macro pastes workbook name to the cell in the workbook where the current macro code is running. If you want to paste workbook name to the cell in the workbook `wbTempName`, change line `With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` to `With wbTempName.ActiveSheet`

Comment: With this code I get a "Method or data member not found error."

Comment: change `With ThisWorkbook` to `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` and specify correct sheet name

Comment: Is there a way I can reference the active worksheet?  The active worksheet is changed based on an optionbutton in a userform that is evaluated prior to calling this subroutine.

Comment: Yes, change `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`